# regular expression in matlab to match decimal in filename

Tags: regex, matlab

I'm trying to match a int or a decimal in matlab using regular expressions

I have: `kabel_2.5cm_proef2.xls` and I want to match `2.5`

Another example: `kabel_5cm_proef1.xls` where I want to match 5

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match int or floating point numbers present before the string `cm`

```
\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=cm)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/uB6uH4/1)

`(?=cm)` positive lookahead asserts that the match must be followed by `cm`

Comment: regex is used for matching purposes only. It won't convert string to a number.

Answer (score 0):

```
\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?!\.|\d)
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yR3mM3/10